# \begin{titlepage} on input line 9 ended by \end{document}

Tags: errors

I get the error message

> \begin{titlepage} on input line 9 ended by \end{document}

with the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openright,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel} % espanol
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} % acentos sin codigo
\usepackage{graphicx} % graficos
\usepackage{multirow} % para las tablas

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}

    \begin{center}
        \vspace*{-1in}
        \begin{figure}[htb]
            \begin{center}

            \end{center}
        \end{figure}

        INGENIER\'IA EN REDES Y TELECOMUNICACIONES\\
        \vspace*{0.15in}
        MY FOUR SEASONS AND A LITTLE MORE \\
        \vspace*{0.6in}
        \begin{large}
            PROYECTO INTEGRADOR\\
        \end{large}
        \vspace*{0.2in}
        \begin{Large}
            \textbf{UNIVERSIDAD POLIT\'ECNICA DE JUVENTINO ROSAS} \\
        \end{Large}
        \vspace*{0.3in}
        \begin{large}
            4 C\\
        \end{large}
        \vspace*{0.3in}
        \rule{80mm}{0.1mm}\\
        \vspace*{0.1in}
        \begin{large}
            Presenta:\\  
            Guerrero Rodríguez Cristina.\\
            Franco Garduño Jairo.\\
            Alejos Alegria Juan Carlos.\\
            Joconoxtle Laguna Pablo Cesar.\\ 

            Dr. Joel Quintanilla Domínguez.\\  
            Ing. Víctor Hugo Mancilla Gracia.\\ 

            Santa Cruz de Juventino Rosas, Gto. 17 de Octubre de 2018.\\ 


        \end{large}

    \end{center}


    \tableofcontents


    \section{Introducci\'on}
    El maltrato infantil es un problema que impregna a toda la sociedad, que a menudo ejerce un impacto negativo devastador en los ni\~nos, no solamente durante la infancia, sino que durante toda la vida.   
    La violencia en M\'exico es un factor determinante de la deserci\'on escolar e incluso, una causa importante de muertes infantiles. Miles de ni\~nos, ni\~nas y adolescentes en M\'exico, crecen en un contexto de violencia cotidiana que deja secuelas profundas e incluso termina cada año con la vida de centenares de ellos.

    El maltrato que se infiere en los primeros cinco a\~nos de vida, puede ser especialmente da\~nino, debido a la vulnerabilidad de estos peque\~nos y al hecho de que los primeros a\~nos de vida se caracterizan por un crecimiento neurobiol\'ogico y psicol\'ogico más rápido que en los años siguientes...


    \section{Problematica}
    En años recientes se ha incrementado el número de niños que ha experimentado alguna forma de maltrato.  
    El presente año se presentaron en México el Estudio del Secretario General de las Naciones Unidas sobre la Violencia contra los Niños y el Informe Nacional sobre Violencia y Salud. Según el Informe Nacional, 2 niños menores de 14 años mueren cada día a causa de la violencia en México.  
    El Sistema Nacional para el Desarrollo Integral de la Familia (DIF) del Distrito Federal recibió un promedio de cuatro casos de maltrato infantil por día entre 2000 y 2002. En casi la mitad de los casos (0.47) la responsable fue la madre, en el 0.29 fue el padre  El Índice de los Derechos de la Niñez y Adolescencia Mexicana de UNICEF México y de su Consejo Consultivo para el rango comprendido entre los 12 y 17 años de edad, muestra preocupantes datos de muertes violentas, especialmente de adolescentes varones.  Según datos de la Secretaría de Salud utilizadas para el Índice, en 2004 cada semana 12 adolescentes fueron asesinados y otros 10 se suicidaron.  
    En el 2005, el Instituto Nacional de Estadística, Geógrafa e Informática (INEGI) registro un total de 677 muertes causadas por homicidios entre los jóvenes de este grupo de edad. 
    Más de 3.000 de ellos, de entre 10 y 19 años, mueren a diario (1,2 millones al años) al menos en 2015  
    Las estadísticas acerca del maltrato físico de los niños son alarmantes.  
    Se estima que cada año cientos de miles de niños reciben abuso y maltrato a manos de sus padres o parientes. Miles mueren. Los que sobreviven el abuso, viven marcados por el trauma emocional que perdura mucho después de que los moretones físicos hayan desaparecido.  
    "Los niños empiezan queriendo a sus padres, al cabo de un tiempo los juzgan, raramente, por no decir nunca, los perdonan"  
    Autor: W. Wilde  

    "El medio mejor para hacer buenos a los niños, es hacerlos felices"  
    Escritor: Oscar Wilde  


    \section{Objetivos}

    \subsection{Objetivo general}
    Realizar un pre-diagn\'ostico psicol\'ogico, para lograr prevenir el maltrato infantil y otros problemas psicol\'ogicos que se desarrollen en la vida de los ni\~nos.


    \subsection{Objetivo especifico}
    Lograr desarrollar una investigaci\'on argumentada sobre el tema que se base en los problemas que hay en la sociedad y que afecta al desarrollo psicol\'ogico del ni\~no. Realizar una investigaci\'on acerca de los proyectos similares a este para poder mejorar la idea y lograr el correcto desarrollo.  
    Investigar sobre distintas herramientas que ayuden a la detecci\'on de alg\'un tipo de maltrato o da\'no psicol\'ogico en los ni\~nos y comenzar a dise\~narlas.
    Comenzar a elegir y dise\~nar el entorno gr\'afico donde se realizar\'a o se llevar\'an a cabo el desarrollo del proyecto.  
    Comenzar a desarrollar el proyecto gr\'aficamente   
    Analizar todo el proyecto para la verificaci\'on del desarrollo correcto del mismo.
    \section{Cronograma de actividades  }

    Este es el cronograma de actividades el cual estaremos realizando durante este tercer cuatrimestre. Adem\'as de que cuenta con las actividades realizadas en los cuatrimestres pasados.  

    4to cuatrimestre:   
    En este cuatrimestre distintas materias nos puede ayudar mucho ya que con los conocimientos de esta materia y los conocimientos previos se puede comenzar a elaborar un prototipo del proyecto.   
    Buscaremos que este proyecto pueda tener un mayor impacto en la audiencia, m\'as aparte de poder ser aplicable; encontraremos la manera en que empleado todos nuestros conocimientos podamos hacer que sea una alternativa viable en el campo de la psic\'ologa. 




    \begin{figure}[htb]
        \begin{center}
            \includegraphics[width=13cm]{./cronograma}
        \end{center}
    \end{figure}    


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE: Add `\end{titlepage}` before `\tableofcontents`, but there are more issues... `large` is no environment and if you really need `\vspace` etc. you're in trouble there; Also don't use `\begin{center} ....\end{center}` within `figure` environment... Please remove also the name of the personas -- I doubt that have granted you permission to transmit them to the internet -- think of the EU - GDPR!

Comment: I can't compile this with `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}`...

Answer (score 2):

You simply have a missing `\end{titlepage}` in your code.

Please see the corrected MWE (I deleted your wrong `\begin{large}`...`\end{large}` and changed it one time to command `\large`, because after that command large font is used until you end group `titlepage`  with `\end{titlepage}`):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openright,12pt]{report}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel} % espanol
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} % acentos sin codigo
\usepackage{graphicx} % graficos
\usepackage{multirow} % para las tablas


\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}

    \begin{center}
        \vspace*{-1in}
        \begin{figure}[htb]
            \begin{center}

            \end{center}
        \end{figure}

        INGENIER\'IA EN REDES Y TELECOMUNICACIONES\\
        \vspace*{0.15in}
        MY FOUR SEASONS AND A LITTLE MORE \\
        \vspace*{0.6in}
\large % <==============================================================
            PROYECTO INTEGRADOR\\
        \vspace*{0.2in}

            \textbf{UNIVERSIDAD POLIT\'ECNICA DE JUVENTINO ROSAS} \\

        \vspace*{0.3in}

            4 C\\

        \vspace*{0.3in}
        \rule{80mm}{0.1mm}\\
        \vspace*{0.1in}

            Presenta:\\  
            Guerrero Rodríguez Cristina.\\
            Franco Garduño Jairo.\\
            Alejos Alegria Juan Carlos.\\
            Joconoxtle Laguna Pablo Cesar.\\ 

            Dr. Joel Quintanilla Domínguez.\\  
            Ing. Víctor Hugo Mancilla Gracia.\\ 

            Santa Cruz de Juventino Rosas, Gto. 17 de Octubre de 2018.\\ 

    \end{center}
\end{titlepage} % <=====================================================

\tableofcontents


\section{Introducci\'on}
El maltrato infantil es un problema que impregna a toda la sociedad, 
que a menudo ejerce un impacto negativo devastador en los ni\~nos, no 
solamente durante la infancia, sino que durante toda la vida.   
    La violencia en M\'exico es un factor determinante de la deserci\'on 
escolar e incluso, una causa importante de muertes infantiles. 
Miles de ni\~nos, ni\~nas y adolescentes en M\'exico, crecen en un 
contexto de violencia cotidiana que deja secuelas profundas e 
incluso termina cada año con la vida de centenares de ellos.

    El maltrato que se infiere en los primeros cinco a\~nos de vida, puede ser especialmente da\~nino, debido a la vulnerabilidad de estos peque\~nos y al hecho de que los primeros a\~nos de vida se caracterizan por un crecimiento neurobiol\'ogico y psicol\'ogico más rápido que en los años siguientes...


    \section{Problematica}
    En años recientes se ha incrementado el número de niños que ha experimentado alguna forma de maltrato.  
    El presente año se presentaron en México el Estudio del Secretario General de las Naciones Unidas sobre la Violencia contra los Niños y el Informe Nacional sobre Violencia y Salud. Según el Informe Nacional, 2 niños menores de 14 años mueren cada día a causa de la violencia en México.  
    El Sistema Nacional para el Desarrollo Integral de la Familia (DIF) del Distrito Federal recibió un promedio de cuatro casos de maltrato infantil por día entre 2000 y 2002. En casi la mitad de los casos (0.47) la responsable fue la madre, en el 0.29 fue el padre  El Índice de los Derechos de la Niñez y Adolescencia Mexicana de UNICEF México y de su Consejo Consultivo para el rango comprendido entre los 12 y 17 años de edad, muestra preocupantes datos de muertes violentas, especialmente de adolescentes varones.  Según datos de la Secretaría de Salud utilizadas para el Índice, en 2004 cada semana 12 adolescentes fueron asesinados y otros 10 se suicidaron.  
    En el 2005, el Instituto Nacional de Estadística, Geógrafa e Informática (INEGI) registro un total de 677 muertes causadas por homicidios entre los jóvenes de este grupo de edad. 
    Más de 3.000 de ellos, de entre 10 y 19 años, mueren a diario (1,2 millones al años) al menos en 2015  
    Las estadísticas acerca del maltrato físico de los niños son alarmantes.  
    Se estima que cada año cientos de miles de niños reciben abuso y maltrato a manos de sus padres o parientes. Miles mueren. Los que sobreviven el abuso, viven marcados por el trauma emocional que perdura mucho después de que los moretones físicos hayan desaparecido.  
    "Los niños empiezan queriendo a sus padres, al cabo de un tiempo los juzgan, raramente, por no decir nunca, los perdonan"  
    Autor: W. Wilde  

    "El medio mejor para hacer buenos a los niños, es hacerlos felices"  
    Escritor: Oscar Wilde  


    \section{Objetivos}

    \subsection{Objetivo general}
    Realizar un pre-diagn\'ostico psicol\'ogico, para lograr prevenir el maltrato infantil y otros problemas psicol\'ogicos que se desarrollen en la vida de los ni\~nos.


    \subsection{Objetivo especifico}
    Lograr desarrollar una investigaci\'on argumentada sobre el tema que se base en los problemas que hay en la sociedad y que afecta al desarrollo psicol\'ogico del ni\~no. Realizar una investigaci\'on acerca de los proyectos similares a este para poder mejorar la idea y lograr el correcto desarrollo.  
    Investigar sobre distintas herramientas que ayuden a la detecci\'on de alg\'un tipo de maltrato o da\'no psicol\'ogico en los ni\~nos y comenzar a dise\~narlas.
    Comenzar a elegir y dise\~nar el entorno gr\'afico donde se realizar\'a o se llevar\'an a cabo el desarrollo del proyecto.  
    Comenzar a desarrollar el proyecto gr\'aficamente   
    Analizar todo el proyecto para la verificaci\'on del desarrollo correcto del mismo.
    \section{Cronograma de actividades  }

    Este es el cronograma de actividades el cual estaremos realizando durante este tercer cuatrimestre. Adem\'as de que cuenta con las actividades realizadas en los cuatrimestres pasados.  

    4to cuatrimestre:   
    En este cuatrimestre distintas materias nos puede ayudar mucho ya que con los conocimientos de esta materia y los conocimientos previos se puede comenzar a elaborar un prototipo del proyecto.   
    Buscaremos que este proyecto pueda tener un mayor impacto en la audiencia, m\'as aparte de poder ser aplicable; encontraremos la manera en que empleado todos nuestros conocimientos podamos hacer que sea una alternativa viable en el campo de la psic\'ologa. 

\begin{figure}[htb]
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=13cm]{example-image}
  \end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

and the resulting title page:

[image: title page]

Comment: The names of the persons are still in the code -- both in the O.P. above and in your answer ;-) 'censoring' them in the screen shot is nice, but... ;-)